# How to make modular constants in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am a strong believer in encapsulation and this is hard using javascript. I want to be able to use constants that are not defined on a global level, but I am unable to accomplish this
Example:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
 <p>
  <b>some examples</b>
 </p>
 <p>
  <script>some.STRING</script><br>
  <script>some.ARRAY.join(' - ')</script>
 </p>
</body>
```

javascript

```
// some.js
var some = (function () {
        return {
            STRING: 'some string',
            ARRAY: ["some", "data", "in", "an", "array"]
        };
    }
);
```

I would like the output to contain the two lines below

```
some string
some - data - in - an - array
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p3kgpx70/4/

Comment: Your `some.js` code is unnecessary bending-over-backwards. You can do the exact same thing with a plain `var some = { STRING: … }`. Javascript doesn't really have immutable constants, and there's no real way to work around that. Closures don't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/p3kgpx70/6/`

```
// some.js
var some = (function () {
        return {
            STRING: 'some string',
            ARRAY: ["some", "data", "in", "an", "array"]
        };
    }
)();
element.innerHTML += some.STRING + "</br>";
element.innerHTML += some.ARRAY.join(' - ');
```

> Error #1: IIFE must be wrapped in `(function(){})()`
>   Error #2: Putting an expression in a script doesn't add its value to the page. You must change the DOM to write value to the page. `document.write(some.STRING)` (by @Barmar) will throw an error if you put it in the `p` element. So, I used element.innerHTML after `some` variable definition to write the value.
>   `#3` (not really an error: instead of `var`, you can use `const` to make `some` a constant.

Now, MORE IMMUTABLE!

```
// some.js
const object = {};
Object.defineProperty(object, "some", {get: function () {
        return {
            STRING: 'some string',
            ARRAY: ["some", "data", "in", "an", "array"]
        };
    }})

element.innerHTML += object.some.STRING + "</br>";
element.innerHTML += object.some.ARRAY.join(' - ');
object.some.STRING = 6;
console.log(object.some); // still not changed
```

In the first code block, if I set some.STRING = 6, the value will be changed. If you want to make it immutable, you must make `object = {}` a constant, then set property `some`'s `getter` equals to your function. Everytime you get the value of `object.some`, it's still the same, even if you change the value of `object.some` like this: `object.some.STRING = 6;`. That's because of the magical function you invented. I wrote the wrapper for you.

In JavaScript, you can't set `getter`/`setter` of a global variable (no parent). Sorry.

Comment: hey, that's not all! it's just partial. i am trying to make `some.STRING = 'a'` impossible. @TEJacobsen

Comment: That's not all. See it edited. don't be in a hurry. WAKE UP!

Comment: Thank you! I am a beginner i javascript and this is a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Putting an expression in a script doesn't add its value to the page. You need to call a function to do that. While the page is loading, you can use `document.write()`.

```
<script>
document.write(some.STRING);
document.write(some.ARRAY.join(' - ');
</script>
```

`document.write()` is old fashioned. It would be better to use DOM manipulation functions like `document.getElementById()` and assigning to `.innerHTML`.

You also didn't assign to `some` correctly. You need to call the function to get the object.

```
var some = (function () {
        return {
            STRING: 'some string',
            ARRAY: ["some", "data", "in", "an", "array"]
        };
    }
)();
```

Or you can forget about the IIFE, and just assign the object directly.

```
var some = {
    STRING: 'some string',
    ARRAY: ["some", "data", "in", "an", "array"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're declaring 'some' to be just a function, not an object. You rather do:

```
// some.js
var some = (function () {
    return {
        STRING: 'some string',
        ARRAY: ["some", "data", "in", "an", "array"]
    };
 }
)();
```

With the last two extra parenthesis to execute the function and get 'some' to be that object.

**However**, 'some' is still a window property that can be manipulated easily. Just a sintactic issue was solved, but no encapsulation is provided. You could just do: 
    some.Array = 'foo'; 
lately in your script and that would be perfectly fine. ES6 keyword 'const' doesn't prevent this: 'const' just only forbid to reassign a variable, not to modify it. So 'const some' wouldn't work to to make those values really constants.

If you're really into encapsulation, you should check closures in javascript and the module pattern, and also should see some ways to build your javascript modularly with browserify or webpack.

Comment: Hey! `const a=0;`
undefined
`a=4`
VM1382:1 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.(…)